# Statistical Inference Exercise 2.10

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

I'm attempting to solve this exercise, but I don't where to start.
The problem is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Did you do the exercise 1.49 where stochastically greater was defined?  Did you use the hint and draw the cdf's?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I donnot know. Is FY(y) <= FU(y)?